# PayPal REST API Vault - Access existing cards not previously saved via Vault?

Tags: api, rest, paypal

If an existing PayPal user has one or more credit cards saved in their PayPal account, and that user is new to my application, are those card details accessible via the Rest API Vault endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

No. When you make a REST call, the end user will be providing you their card data directly. The credit cards in their PayPal account are backup funding sources. While it's possible you could get paid through them, there's no way for you to know because the payment will be shown as their PayPal account only.